# Jquery hover event + css.animate

Tags: jquery, hover, jquery-animate, mouseevent

I have created a simple tool-tip that fadesIn when you hover over the ( i ) icon. The icon comes up when hovering over a album cover. There at the moment is a strange bug I think that it is due to .more-info opacity css animate jQuery method. I was wondering how to fix this or how to change the code that it would work.

bug: When hovering over the ( i ) icon so that the tool-tip comes up and then leaving it or the ( i ) icon the tool-tip fadesOut but if you hover back on the album cover before it is completely fadenOut it flashes a little bit. The tool-tip should only come up when hovering over the ( i ) icon or hovering over the tool-tip it self.

VIDEO of the bug: http://www.screenr.com/tIJ8

The site whit the problem: http://www.midnightlisteners.com/

The tool-tip css file: http://www.midnightlisteners.com/wp-content/themes/midnightlisteners-v2.0wp/css/the-tooltip.css

HTML code:

```
<div class="more-info">
    <div class="the-tooltip top center black">
        <span class="too-tip-text">
        <h3>Similar than: <span><?php the_title(); ?> &rsaquo; </span></h3>
        <div class="related">
           <ul>
           </ul>
        </div>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

​

jQuery code:

```
 $(".play").mouseenter(function() {
        $(this).next('.more-info').stop(true, false).animate({
            opacity: '1'
        }, 800, 'linear');
        $(".more-info").mouseenter(function() {
            $(this).stop(true).animate({
                opacity: '1'
            }, 800, 'linear');
        });
    });
    $(".play").mouseleave(function() {
        $(this).next('.more-info').stop(true, false).animate({
            opacity: '0'
        }, 1000, 'linear');
        $(".more-info").mouseleave(function() {
            $(this).stop(true).animate({
                opacity: '0'
            }, 1000, 'linear');
        });
    });


    $(".more-info").mouseenter(function() {
        clearTimeout($(this).data('timeoutId'));
        $(this).find(".the-tooltip").fadeIn('150', 'linear');
    }).mouseleave(function() {
        var someElement = $(this);
        var timeoutId = setTimeout(function() {
            someElement.find(".the-tooltip").fadeOut('150', 'linear');
        }, 1200);
        //set the timeoutId, allowing us to clear this trigger if the mouse comes back over
        someElement.data('timeoutId', timeoutId);
    });
```

CSS code:

```
.more-info{
    position: absolute;
    top: 75px;
    left: 85px;
    z-index: 9999;
    display: block;
    width: 19px;
    height: 18px;
    background: transparent url(images/midnightlisteners-bgs-matrix.png) no-repeat -60px -44px;
    cursor: pointer;
    opacity: 0;
    display: block;
}

.more-info:hover{

}​
```

EDIT: How to make the code simpler and not repeating it self. how to implement var elements

```
$(".play").mouseenter(function(){
        $(this).next('.more-info').stop(true, false).animate({
            opacity: '1'
            }, 800, 'linear');
        $(".more-info").mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).stop(true).animate({
                opacity: '1'
                }, 800, 'linear');
        });
        $(".the-tooltip-wrap").mouseenter(function(){
            $(this).prev(".more-info").stop(true).animate({
                opacity: '1'
                }, 800, 'linear');
        });
    });
    $(".play").mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).next('.more-info').stop(true, false).animate({
            opacity: '0'
            }, 1000, 'linear');
        $(".more-info").mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).stop(true).animate({
                opacity: '0'
                }, 1000, 'linear');
        });
        $(".the-tooltip-wrap").mouseleave(function(){
            $(this).prev(".more-info").stop(true).animate({
                opacity: '0'
                }, 1000, 'linear');
        }); 
    });
```

​

Comment: It might be easier if you post your examples on this page

Comment: "I don't always test my code, but when I do, I make sure I do it on the production server."

Comment: Not really noticing this problem myself, but your are binding a new event handler to `.more-info` every time your mouse enter and leave any of the `.play` elements. That will become a shitload of handlers. Try move them out of the enter/leave handlers and see if that helps.

Comment: Ah, now I see. You should move out the tooltip out of the play/more-info container. Animating both the child and parent opacity at the same time is most likely the cause of this issue.

Comment: Hi Marcus Ekwall, Could you explain a little bit more i am fairly new to jQuery. (Try move them out of the enter/leave handlers).

Comment: Marcus Ekwall have you any suggestions for how to make the css.animate code smaller and better. It is working now thanks to you :) but the code repeats itself a lot. I think i should use variables but i don't know how. See EDIT above. Thanks